# "My goodness!" Mine? Goodness?

Tags: etymology, idioms, minced-oaths

Why do we say *my goodness*?  It doesn't sound appropriate for the contexts in which it is used.  Both the *my* and the *goodness* don’t seem to bear on a surprising or startling situation.  When was it started, and why?

Comment: What epithet **does** bear on a surprising situation?  That is kind of the point of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Phrase Doctor](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/minced-oath.html) writes that *my goodness* is a minced oath:

> My goodness --> My God
>
> My gosh --> My God

So the phrase was used instead of swearing, with *goodness* being a euphemism. The Oxford English Dictionary adds that *goodness!* has an established meaning in this vein, writing:

> In various exclamatory phrases, in which the original reference was to the goodness of God (cf. sense 2a above), as goodness gracious!, goodness (only) knows! , †for goodness!, for goodness' sake!, in the name of goodness!, (I wish) to goodness! , surely to goodness!, thank goodness!, etc., or simply goodness!

The first written usage is by Shakespeare, who wrote:

> 1623    Shakespeare & J. Fletcher Henry VIII Prol. 23   Therefore, for Goodnesse sake, and as you are knowne The First and Happiest Hearers of the Towne, Be sad, as we would make ye.

There isn't a notation about the first written use of *my goodness*, but it definitely uses the sense of *goodness* which has been around since the 1600s.

Comment: It's not exactly on a daily basis, but I have been known to exclaim *"Landsakes and lawksamussy!"* as being slightly more socially acceptable than *"Fuck me sideways with a seven-foot bargepole!"*. To be honest, I feel that in the UK today, *"Lord have mercy!"* would probablly raise more eyebrows than either of those two.

Answer (score 3):

It's a socially acceptable way of saying *Oh my god!* without offence. It's not just a pun, but also a subtle counter to those who say *Oh my god* by switching the offensive part to something completely opposite: *cursing God* (bad) -> *goodness*

Answer (score 1):

*Goodness* is an euphemism for *God*.