# Where does “goodness me” come from?

Tags: etymology, interjections

The expression [“my goodness”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40649/my-goodness-mine-goodness) always seemed clear to me, as it is a simple bowdlerisation of “my God”, as are many expletives. However, I have heard many times the expression **“[goodness me!](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/goodness_me)”**, which Google confirms exist (and is less used than “my Goodness”):

[image: ngram]

This expression doesn't make any sense to me on the construction. *Goodness* is a noun, so why is it formed that way? Is it an alteration of “my goodness”, or was it formed somewhat independently? Is it a shortening of a longer expression, which would explain its weird grammatical form?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["My goodness!" Mine? Goodness?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40649/my-goodness-mine-goodness)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it is a shortening of the phrase *goodness gracious me* which I think is a mincing of the oath *God grace me*, which would be a request for God's help.

This is because part of the etymology of [gracious](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gracious&allowed_in_frame=0) is

> filled with God's grace

Shortening phrases is something typical of English, and has left us with three other minces:

1. Goodness gracious
2. Goodness me
3. Gracious me