# "My goodness" expressed after hearing sad news?

Tags: meaning

Recently my cat died. He escaped my house and was attacked by a dog. Sadly he didn't survive.

I emailed a male acquaintance ( were not close friends, live long distance, communication is not daily). He's offered a listening ear if I need one. I told him the above ,and that I was feeling sad.

His response by email "My goodness. My heartfelt condolences."

My goodness is expressing surprise?

Comment: Yes, it's a euphamism of "My God" I think.

Comment: When I read the second sentence, I was shocked (I love animals) and my first reaction was, *oh, my goodness!* It is a euphamism for the much more used *Oh my God!* or OMG.

Comment: @Susan: So if you emailed a colleague at work that your cat had died in such circumstances, how would *you* feel if the reply email said *"OMG. My heartfelt condolences."*? Personally, my first thought would probably be *"That looks rather odd without an exclamation mark."* Then I'd think *"How crass!"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - people use OMG all the time. I just ended the sentence there. How can you possibly think that's crass given the expletives you use?!? (Do you know how to type an interrobang? Reg D does.)

Comment: @Susan: My guess is well over 90% of all instances of OMG are actually expressing little more than *"Wow!"* or *"Golly gosh!"* (or perhaps *"Corks!"* in my admittedly idiosyncratic vernacular). Just so we know, my definition of **crass** there is *Grossly stupid, ‘dense’; **grossly insensitive** or unrefined*. Not "rude, coarse, foul-mouthed", if that's what you were thinking. I get my ‽‽interrobangs‽‽‽‽‽ and such by typing the word into google so I can cut&paste from the first useful result.

Comment: So using "My goodness" is showing insensitivity or shock? Were not colleagues.Acquaintances. I know sometimes you here something shocking or sad you

Comment: For example you hear of tragedy in the news, something shocking, oh my gosh type feeling.

Answer (score 0):

My goodness would express shock or surprise but more accurately it is a small prayer.  It is derived from "My God".  I think it is an appropriate thing to say in your context.

Comment: With something as trivial and obvious as this, you might try searching for an existing duplicate. Apart from the one I closevoted against, there's also [Where does “goodness me” come from?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40837/where-does-goodness-me-come-from) and probably others. People's standards may differ, but I personally do *not* think it's an appropriate thing to write in an email, given OP's *exact* context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - probably duplicate of the one under post.  I saw the goodness me and thought this was a little different.